# How do I print all POST results when a form is submitted?

Tags: php, post, echo

I need to see all of the `POST` results that are submitted to the server for testing.

What would be an example of how I can create a new file to submit to that will echo out all of the fields which were submitted with that form?

It's dynamic, so some fields may have a name/ID of `field1, field2, field3`, etc.

Comment: The reason why some of the solutions suggested doesn't look neat is because they rely on newlines, but are interpreted as HTML in the browser. Simply add `echo "<pre>";` before the var_dump() or print_r().

Answer (score 216, accepted):

All the values are stored in the `$_POST` collection

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

or if you want something fancier that is easier to read use a foreach loop to loop through the `$_POST` collection and print the values.

```
<table>
<?php 


    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }


?>
</table>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be $_REQUEST? (if not $_POST)

Comment: Meant for it to be $_POST.  Had a similar script for $_SERVER variables that I grabbed but failed to make that small edit.  Thanks.

Comment: Probably worth highlighting kb.'s comment under the answer, about simply puting `var_dump` or `print_r` output between HTML `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 24):

You could try [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php):

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

Comment: This works, but is there anyway to make it a bit neater? Such as a list going down the page that just says "Field ID: value"?

Comment: @Zoolander See kb.'s comment under the answer, about simply puting `var_dump` or `print_r` output between HTML `<pre>` tags.

Comment: var_dump shorter and more clear

Answer (score 13):

Simply:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);

    //Or:
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
        echo $key.'='.$value.'<br />';
?>
```

Answer (score 10):

You may mean something like this:

```
<?php
    $output = var_export($_POST, true);
    error_log($output, 0, "/path/to/file.log");
?>
```

Comment: $output = var_export($_POST, true);
This is the best one, most of the time, echo it or write to file

Answer (score 4):

You could use something as simple as this

```
<?php
   print_r($_POST);
?>
```

This would make it a bit more viewable:

```
<?php
   echo str_replace('  ', '&nbsp; ', nl2br(print_r($_POST, true)));
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely use `var_dump`, but you mentioned you are in front-end development. I am sure you would know this, but just as a reminder, use Firefox's [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) or Chrome's / Internet Explorer's developers tool and check for the post. Post goes through hearders, and you should be able to check it from there too.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) didn't do anything for me - unlike $_GET.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (! function_exists('d'))
{
    // Debugger
    function d($var, $exit = 0)
    {
        // Only output on localhost
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')
        {
            return;
        }

        echo "\n[degug_output_BEGIN]<pre>\n";
        echo var_export($var, 1);
        echo "\n</pre>[degug_output_END]\n";

        if ($exit)
            exit;
    }
}

// Call:
d($_POST);
```

---

Bonus: Check [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) too add tracing to your debugging.