# Html/php script (POST method) works on local host but doesn't do anything on my hosting website

Tags: php, html

I want to make a script for my  website that it shows a  form and a visitor can write his email and a message this is the  code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Feedback</title>
</head>
<body>

        <form  method="post" action="post.php" >
        Email<input name="email" type="text" ><br/>

        Message<input name="message" type="text" ><br/>



        <input type="submit" ">
        </form>         

</body>


</html>
```

now with a php script (post.php) I want to collect this information and save it to a text file (information.txt). This is the script:

```
<?php

$email = $_POST["email"];
$message =  $_POST["message"];

$f = fopen("information.txt", "w");
fwrite($f,"Email: $email\r\nMessage:  $message");
fclose($f);

?>
```

That works locally but when I upload those files to my control panel on my hosting website it doesn't work (notice that I give the right paths)

Comment: Does the file information.txt exist on your server before you start writing to it?  Check your server log for an error.  It might be a permissions thing.

Comment: I had made the text file and my permissions are ok (rw-rw-rw-)

Comment: You might also want the type of that e-mail input field to be "email". Then the browser can at least save the innocent end-user from their own typos. It doesn't stop a malicious user or someone with an old browser from giving you an invalid e-mail, of course, but it does at least help with the sanity checking.

Comment: when you want to do changes, no need to [delete the question and repost](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/251482/html-php-script-post-method-works-on-local-host-but-doesnt-do-anything-on-my). You can simply [edit] it

Comment: Ok but it doesn't even works :(

Comment: @pacos I wouldn't worry too much about that right now- you'll notice pretty much every question on SO and here is about something that didn't / doesn't work. So, you have our commiserations. How does it not work? Does the browser hang? Does it return the page you expected it to return? Are there errors in the server logs? Errors in the returned page (Use View Source to see whether there might be error messages hidden in the returned page. If there are, you'll also want to take your server out of debug mode)? Also, was your server in debug mode when you tested it, and in production mode now?

Comment: When i click on submit i takes me to a url "http://domain/folder/post.php"  but it does not appear something  there are no errors.To your answer how it does not work--i want to write those informations to a text file and it doesn't do it like there isn't script

Comment: First things first - what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get a blank page? An error? Do you have error reporting enabled on your server?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code; besides maybe taking out the extra quote in `<input type="submit" ">` so try `<input type="submit">` but either way worked for me on FF. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @HorusKol i mean that the program does not write the given informations to the text file.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it doesn't report me any error

Comment: Try to add this and let us know the output ...
`$f = fopen("information.txt", "w");
echo $f;
while($f){
fwrite($f,"Email: $email\r\nMessage:  $message");
fclose($f);
echo "<br/>done.";
}`

Comment: @MAZux suddenly it works! But i have an other problem now when i click on submit button it shows me these messages :

Comment: @MAZux Warning:fwrite():8 is not a valid stream resource in /home/******/public_html/funny_pictures/post.php on line 10


Warning:fwrite():8 is not a valid stream resource in /home/*****/public_html/funny_pictures/post.php on line 11

and it continues until browser crash

Comment: i fix the continuing loop now it runs 1 time only but i have this error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/*****/public_html/funny_pictures/post.php on line 3

Comment: i erase this line but now it tells me that :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/******/public_html/funny_pictures/post.php on line 3

Comment: @pacos Tell me what is on line 3,plz don't forget to let us know everything that gonna be not clear enough for us :(

Comment: @ MAZux line 1:<?php
line 2:$a=1
line 3:$email = $_POST["email"];
line 4:$message =  $_POST["message"];
$f = fopen("information.txt", "w");
echo $f;
while($a<2 AND $f){ 

fwrite($f,"Email: $email\r\nMessage: $message"); 
fclose($f); 
echo "<br/>done.";
$a=$a+1 

}

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the POST variables on your post.php file using this thread [How do I print all POST results when a form is submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332718/how-to-print-all-post-results-when-a-form-is-submitted)

This will tell you if indeed the values are transmitting across your web server. I also noticed one more thing which seems to be odd with your submit button code (could be a copy/paste issue?):

Replace

```
<input type="submit" ">
```

With

```
<input type="submit">
```

Again, that may just be an error you made while copying/pasting here. Let us know if this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fix it, this is the right code:

```
<?php
$a=1;
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message =  $_POST["message"];
$f = fopen("information.txt", "w");
echo $f;

while($a<2 AND $f)
{ 
fwrite($f,"Email: $email\r\nMessage: $message"); 
fclose($f); 
$a=$a+1;
}
?>
```