# Alert message on sending email not showing up

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

On sending the email by clicking the send message button an alert box should show up, but it is not coming up neither it is showing inquiry sent successfully nor it is showing email not sent I don't know where I'm going wrong. Please help me resolve this issue.
Any help will be highly appreciable. I'm attaching herewith a part of my contact.php code and my mail.php code.
Thank You

> contact.php

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="mail.php">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" type="text" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" type="email" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Subject</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Message</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="" rows="10" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-right"><br>
                    
                        <button class="btn btn-primary solid blank button"  id="btn" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Send Message</button>
                    
                    </div>
    
                </form>
```

> mail.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$to = "contact@imatrixautomation.com";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$message .="\r\n from: $email";


if(mail ($to, $subject, $name,  $message)){
    echo "<script>alert('Enquiry sent successfully!');</script>";
   
}
    else
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Mail was not sent. Please try again later');</script>";
    }
}


header('Location: https://imatrixautomation.com/contact.php');
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using if(isset($\_POST\['submit'\])) to not display echo when script is open is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775512/using-ifisset-postsubmit-to-not-display-echo-when-script-is-open-is-not)

Comment: I added name attribute but still not working

Comment: As in, not even one of the alerts? Try dumping the post values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332718/how-do-i-print-all-post-results-when-a-form-is-submitted

Comment: yes none of the alerts is working

Comment: Dump the post values

Answer (score 0):

In the contact.php file

**name="submit"** is missing for the submit button.

This line should be:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary solid blank button"  id="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Send Message</button>
```

Explanation:
Currently the

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

always evaluates to FALSE as  POST['submit'] is empty  so it continues at the   header()...

################

try this code as mail.php  and tell us what happens ;-)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
    echo "submit is set to {$_POST['submit']} and now we send the email<br>";

$to = "contact@imatrixautomation.com"; 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$message .="\r\n from: $email";


if(mail ($to, $subject, $name,  $message)){
    echo "Enquiry sent successfully!<br>";
   
}
    else
    {
    echo "Mail was not sent. Please try again later<br>";
    }
} else{

echo"submit is not set<br>"; 
}

echo "after the if condition";


exit;

?>
```

Here i have the new contact.php file - just copy paste this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
</head>

<body>
    
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="mail.php">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" type="text" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" type="email" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Subject</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Message</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="" rows="10" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-right"><br>
                    
                        <button class="btn btn-primary solid blank button"  id="btn" type="submit" name ="submit" value="submit">Send Message</button>
                    
                    </div>
    
                </form>    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added name attribute but still not working

Comment: Strange .. 
Could you please insert the code of the contact.php in a comment or update it above? 

Try to use a standard echo "it worked"  instead of the alert just in case you have a popup blocker 
and insert a temporary echo in both parts of the if condition to see which branch is taken.

Comment: I put exactly your code adding the name attribute and only changed the email address and put it on one of my servers and it worked perfectly. 

and i just got the email ;-) 

MAYBE there is a problem with the mail.php script so that aborts with an error 500?  and nothing is displayed at all??

Comment: I  edited my post to insert some code to reduce the numbers of possible problems. 
please try this. 

possible problems: on client or server 
Javascript popups are not allowed  -  
     Popup Blocker   /AdBlocker - 
     JS is not allowed - 
mail() does not work - 

If possible it look into your server log to see if you have any fatal errors

Comment: It is showing:-   submit is not set after the if condition

Comment: Please suggest something since it is working on your system,  it would be a great help

Comment: @Soumya 
I have updated my answer above yesterday and included the php code you can use on your webpage to find out the problem.   just copy paste it as the  mail.php file and tell us what is displayed on your screen. 

it can be found below 

**try this code as mail.php and tell us what happens ;-) **

Comment: Sorry - did not see your reply of yesterday: 
If you get this messages displayed then you still have a problem in the contact.php file.

Please update the complete code of the current contact.php file in your original question.  or comment here with the line containing the button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226671/discussion-between-alexander-dobernig-and-soumya).

Answer (score 0):

you should add name to your button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary solid blank button"  id="btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Send Message</button>
```

also as you're redirecting by changing header it won't show you the alert as alert was on different page.

try this code

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" type="text" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" type="email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Subject</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="" rows="10" required></textarea>
</div>
<div class="text-right"><br>
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary solid blank button"  id="btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Send Message</button>

</div>
</form>
```

and below this write your php code in same file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "contact@imatrixautomation.com";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$message .= "\r\n from: $email";


if(mail($to, $subject, $name, $message)) {
    echo "<script>alert('Enquiry sent successfully!');</script>";
    
}
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Mail was not sent. Please try again later'); 
          </script>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I added name attribute but still not working

Comment: @Soumya i have updated the code, please check

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<button class="btn btn-primary solid blank button"  id="btn" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Send Message</button>
```

To

```
<input class="btn btn-primary solid blank button"  id="btn" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```